# QGIS problem with upgrading python version

Tags: pyqgis, installation

I would like to upgrade my Python version to QGIS. I launched OSGeo4W and followed the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPMHhgR-r7E&ab_channel=GEO2004

everything was fine until I executed the following command:

```
 python.exe m-pip install sklearn
```

and I got the error like this:

**WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\apps\Python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.**

When I repeated it under the indicated directory, the problem is exactly the same.

[image]

I have several errors, which I don't know how to sort out

This solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139834/python-3-is-not-upgrading-pip-am-i-linking-a-wrong-directory

How can I upgrade the pip library for my QGIS?

wasn't helpful so far

Comment: Probably not a good idea to upgrade the Python that QGIS is working on. That would probably cause a lot of plugins to stop working.

Comment: So what is the different way of importing the python libraries into QGIS?

Comment: Just run "pip install sklearn" in the OSgeo4W shell.

Comment: Did you check "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: No, I didn't to be honest, thank you